# Updated position Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a bullet that has to hit a constantly moving enemy.

So, in BulletScript, I have declared a Transform

```
public Transform enemy;               //and assigned enemy object to it that is continuously moving and changing its position
```

Now, when I try to use `enemy.position` in bullet script so as to hit it, `enemy.position`gives the position at which the enemy strted and not the position at which it was when bulletprefab was shot.

How can I get the updated position of enemy object every time bulletprefab is instantiated.

This is how I am changing the enemy's position:

```
void Update () {
        float amttomove = currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate (Vector3.left * amttomove);
        if (transform.position.x < 0f) 
            setposandspeed();
    }
    void setposandspeed()
    {
        x = 11.5f;
        z = 0.0f;
        currentSpeed = Random.Range (MinSpeed, MaxSpeed);
        y = Random.Range (0f, 2.5f);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    }
```

This is where  tried to use enemy's position in bulletscript:

```
float target_Distance = Vector3.Distance(Projectile.position, Target.transform.position );
```

It is called inside Start() of bulletscript

This is where I instantiated the bullet in Player class:

Inside Updated method:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y + collider.bounds.size.y / 2);
            Instantiate (bulletprefab, position, Quaternion.identity);  
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a few more details like the code where you instantiate the bullet? enemy.transform.position should do the job when placed in the right place :)

Comment: I am instantiating bullet in Player script but using enemy.position in bulletscript (I have whole code of moving the bullet in BulletScript), just the prefab instantiation is done is Player script and enemy.position is supposed to be used in guiding the bullet path , any idea with that scenario? @GlabbichRulz

Comment: @GlabbichRulz : Updated the question, have a look ,please?

Comment: have you tried outputting the position in the console to see if you get the right positions? maybe you are receiving wrong values, try using public Gameobject player at the beginning, drag the object in the inspector and then use player.transform.position

Comment: @GlabbichRulz: Solved :) There were lot of things that needed to be changed, proper instantiation of class and Vector3. Thank you

Comment: Haha, i know that feeling :D In Unity, a Bug never comes alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> enemy.position in bullet script so as to hit it, enemy.positiongives
>   the position at which the enemy strted and not the position at which
>   it was when bulletprefab was shot.

No, `enemy.position` will return the current position of the enemy, suitable if you want your projectile follow the enemy.

If you are instantiating dynamically your projectiles (`BullerScript`) and want to shoot them toward the position the enemy is during the shoot frame, record it just after bullet is instantiated for example:

```
class BulletScript : MonoBehavior
{

   public Vector3 targetPos;

   void Update()
   {
      //move toward targetPos
   }
}

BulletScript bullet = GameObject.Instantiate(bulletPrefab,shootPosition) as BulletScript;
bullet.targetPos = enemyPosition;
```